# Why was this 'obsolete' flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging, editing

[This answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/27093/alternating-paths-in-niagara/27107#27107) was commented on by the poster, and the comment should have been part of the answer. So I edited the comment into the answer, and flagged the comment as obsolete.

This flag was declined:

[image]

The information is 100% redundant. Why not delete it?

Comment: Pat, the answer on the duplicate says "When the content of the comments has been fully incorporated into an answer, or an issue has been unambiguously resolved to the satisfaction of all parties, then I tend to delete them immediately." That would seem to apply here, but obviously you don't think so. Could you explain?

Comment: Your flag was probably declined by a moderator on this site who adheres to some rather... "unique" flag handling rules. He will not delete comments that are recent unless they are actively harmful, even if they are truly obsolete. You should consider the flags on this site to read like "obsolete *and old*", "not constructive *and actively harmful*", "too chatty *and actively harmful*", etc.